# SQL Clob search on multiple strings in Clob with join, possibly REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to extract multiple strings from a clob with REGEXP_SUBSTR using Oracle SQL.

clob_field example:

```
xxx xxx"xxxxxxxYY=1234xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"xx       xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
xxxxx"xxxxxxxYY=2345xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx"xxxx  xxxxxxxxxx  
xxx  xxxxx"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxYY=34567xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx"xxxxxxxxxxxx  
xxxx"xxxxxYY=4567xx.xxxxxx"xxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx
```

I've tried:

```
select a.id, regexp_substr(b.clob_field,'YY=',",[^"]+"') "clob_result"  
from table1 a, table2 b  
where a.id = b.id
```

The desired result from joined query example is:

```
id       clob_result  
1        xxxxxxxYY=1234xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx  
1        xxxxxxxYY=2345xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx  
1        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxYY=34567xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx  
1        xxxxxYY=4567xx.xxxxxx
```

Not clear how to search string containing 'YY=', and return the entire string quoted with " at the beginning and end.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE to get multiple occurences, along with the surrounding double quotes. You can then use TRIM/REPLACE to remove them.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27123)

```
with x(y) as (
    select 'xxxx"xxxxxxxYY=1234xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"xx       xxxxx' from dual union all 
    select 'xx"xxxxxxxYY=2345xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx"xxx xxx' from dual union all 
    select 'xxx"xxxxxxxxxxxxYY=34567xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx"xxxxxxxxx' from dual union all 
    select 'x"xxxxxYY=4567xx.xxxxxx"xx"xxxxxYY=8787xx.xxxx"xx' from dual
    )
select y, replace(trim('"' from regexp_replace(y,
                                               '("[^"]*YY=[^"]*")|(.)',
                                               '\1'
                                              )  -- this will remove anything that is not matched by the regex
                      ),
                  '""',
                  ','
                 ) as clob_result
from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27123/0)**:

```
|                                                 Y |                               CLOB_RESULT |
|---------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| xxxx"xxxxxxxYY=1234xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"xx       xxxxx |             xxxxxxxYY=1234xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx |
| xx"xxxxxxxYY=2345xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx"xxx xxx |    xxxxxxxYY=2345xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx |
| xxx"xxxxxxxxxxxxYY=34567xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx"xxxxxxxxx |       xxxxxxxxxxxxYY=34567xxxxx.xxx.xxxxx |
| x"xxxxxYY=4567xx.xxxxxx"xx"xxxxxYY=8787xx.xxxx"xx | xxxxxYY=4567xx.xxxxxx,xxxxxYY=8787xx.xxxx |
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Peach, and again Egor.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  regexp_substr(string,'"([^"]*YY=[^"]*)"', 1, 1, '', 1) as clob_result
from your_table
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cede7/1)

---

```
  select 
    id, occ,
    regexp_substr(string,'"([^"]*YY=[^"]*)"', 1, occ, '', 1) as clob_result
  from your_table,
       (select level occ from dual connect by level < 99)
  where occ <= regexp_count(string,'"([^"]*YY=[^"]*)"')
  order by id, occ
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe007/1)

Comment: Thank you Egor! That works great, yet only returns the first occurrence. Any advice to return all occurrences as in 'desired result' example?

Comment: @user3466045 - Appended.